# NumberFormatException in android, parseDouble GeoPoint

Tags: android

Having this problem with my android app

I struggled with this for some time now, and went through alot of similar threads but never really solved it. I haven't managed to recreate the crash my self but i get crash-reports from other users

**Here is a crash-report:**

```js
java.lang.NumberFormatException: -
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.initialParse(FloatingPointParser.java:149)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:281)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
at polis.koll.HelloMapView.loadallmarkers(HelloMapView.java:665)
at polis.koll.HelloMapView.access$10(HelloMapView.java:611)
at polis.koll.HelloMapView$6.run(HelloMapView.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

**And here is my code,** the last line seem to be to one generating the error

```js
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
        "http://www.mysite.com/xml.php");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        //System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;
        gotsnr = "";
        gotmarkers = 0;
        LocationOverlay locationOverlay = new LocationOverlay(mapView, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.polis), mContext);

        if (sitesList !=null){
        for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getSnr().size(); i++) {
        gotsnr = sitesList.getSnr().get(i);
        gotmarkers = (i);
        //if (gotsnr !=""){ 
        if (sitesList.getLat().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("")||sitesList.getLat().get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
            // Empty, do nothing

        } else{

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint( new Double(Double.parseDouble(sitesList.getLat().get(i)) * 1e6).intValue() , new Double(Double.parseDouble(sitesList.getLng().get(i)) * 1e6).intValue());
```

***** Edit below in replie to @kcoppock

Could this do the trick?

```
double dlat = 0;
double dlng = 0;

            if (sitesList.getLat().get(i) !=null && !"".equals(sitesList.getLat().get(i)) ){
                    try {
                       dlat = Double.parseDouble(sitesList.getLat().get(i));
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                       //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            if (sitesList.getLng().get(i) !=null && !"".equals(sitesList.getLng().get(i)) ){
                try {
                    dlng = Double.parseDouble(sitesList.getLng().get(i));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                   //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if (dlat !=0  && dlng !=0){

            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint( new Double(dlat * 1e6).intValue() , new Double(dlng * 1e6).intValue());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not handling the `NumberFormatException` in the first place, which is bad practice even if you weren't having crashes. Split that line up, parse the doubles first, and be sure to catch the `NumberFormatException` and handle it appropriately (e.g. throw an alert dialog, place a default value, etc.) in case for some reason the value in `getLat()` or `getLon()` are not parseable, which is what is apparently happening in these cases.

```
double lat = 0, lng = 0;
String sLat = sitesList.getLat().get(i);
String sLng = sitesList.getLng().get(i);
GeoPoint point;

try {
    lat = Double.parseDouble(sLat);
    lng = Double.parseDouble(sLng);

    //If it gets here, they parsed successfully
    point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1e6), (int)(lng * 1e6));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.e("TAG", "Couldn't parse latitude and/or longitude");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replie @kcoppock ! think you are right, i edited my post above, do you think that fix should be sufficient ?

Comment: @Jerry: I would probably do something like the above example (I edited one in). It depends on whether the process should completely fail if the points cannot be parsed, or if some other logical process should happen. The way this example is, it tries to parse both, and if either of them fails, it falls instantly to the catch block, and doesn't execute the `new GeoPoint` line.

Comment: Thanks :) Looks much better then mine