# NumberFormatException in Lat Lng Values

Tags: android, google-maps, numberformatexception

I am getting latitude and longitude values in activity, I am getting these both are String values here I have to cover double and using this latitude and longitude value I want to show locations on map. But while converting String to double it shows error `NumberFormatException` in my `logcat`. But I converted using `Double.parseDouble("");`

My code:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //locationManger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    _googleMap.clear();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
        String>>) 
            getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayList");
         if(arl.size()!=0){
            for(int j = 0;j<arl.size();j++){


          Log.e("SIZE", ""+arl.size());
           Log.e(" NEW LAT",arl.get(j).get("lat").toString());
          Log.e(" NEW LONG",arl.get(j).get("lng").toString());
          Log.e(" NEW ADDRESS",arl.get(j).get("address").toString());
          Log.e(" NEW CTIME",arl.get(j).get("ctime").toString());
          String lat =arl.get(j).get("lat").toString();
          String lng =arl.get(j).get("lng").toString();
          double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
          double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng);

          LatLng latLng =new LatLng(Hlat, Hlong);

          Marker perth = _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

          .position(latLng)

     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
          .flat(true));

            }

    }
         else{

    if(location!=null){
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double langitude = location.getLongitude();


        latLongDetails.setLat(latitude);
        latLongDetails.setLongi(langitude);

        Log.e("lat",""+ latLongDetails.getLat());
        Log.e("long", ""+latLongDetails.getLongi());

        LatLng latlang = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);
        //LatLngBounds curScreen = 
           _googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
        //curScreen.contains(latlang);
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

        _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition)); 
        _googleMap.addMarker(new   
          MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));

    }
    }
```

Error LogCat:

```
    03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseDouble(FloatingPointParser.java:267)
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:318)
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634):    at com.technowellServices.locationfind.GetLatLongForTPActivity.onLocationChanged(GetLatLongForTPActivity.java:161)
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:227)
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:160)
03-04 14:52:01.765: E/AndroidRuntime(24634):    at android.location.L
ocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:176)
```

How to avoid this ?

Comment: exactly which line is this: GetLatLongForTPActivity.java:161

Comment: Have you get data from server??

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710196/numberformatexception-in-android-parsedouble-geopoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally Whenever you are trying to over a Number String ( "1234" ) into Number ( 1234 ), at that time if there is any white space in the number then it throws, `NumberFormatException`. To avoid it always use `trim()` method.

Instead of these lines,

```
double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng);
```

Try this,

```
if ( !lat.trim().equals("") && !lng.trim().equals("") ) 
{
     double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
     double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng.trim());
}
```

Comment: i have to use another values which are coming from array list

Comment: @Durga, please check now.

Comment: @Durga, any progress ?

Comment: Its ok. I am happy that it is working. You welcome. :)

Comment: Why you again de-accept my answer ? See at a time you can "accept" only one answer out of given answers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48948/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-durga)

Comment: @Durga, its ok. What I am saying is, You can not accept two answers at a time. So once you tick mark an answer as accepted, you shouldn't accept another answer. Instead you can upvote the other answer that helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

You must check your `lat` and `lng` values are `NULL` or not like:

```
if (!lat.trim().equals("") && !lng.trim().equals("") ) 
{
 double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat);
 double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng);
}
```

`Exception` is thrown because your `lat` and `lng` values found `NULL` or blank and you convert that `NULL` value into `Double`, so.